# How to replace a part of an expression in a text file in Windows PowerShell?

Tags: powershell, replace

I am completely new to coding/PowerShell, so sorry for my inability to figure it out on my own.
I have a text file (lit.bib) with ~250.000 lines. I want to replace the expression `{\textunderscore }` by `_` whenever it occurs and the file to be saved as "lit_t.bib". For example, I want the line

```
doi = {10.1007/978-3-319-89999-2{\textunderscore }198}
```

to be changed into

```
doi = {10.1007/978-3-319-89999-2_198}
```

How can I do that?

```
(Get-Content lit.bib) -replace '{\textunderscore }', '_' | Out-File -encoding UTF8 lit_t.bib
```

Thanks!

Comment: PowerShell's [`-replace`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40683667/45375) _operator_ is _regex_-based (and case-_insensitive_ by default). To perform _literal_ replacements, ``\``-escape metacharacters in the pattern or escape them with  `[regex]::Escape()`.

Comment: By contrast, the `[string]` type's [`.Replace()`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.String.Replace) _method_- as shown in Santiago's answer - performs _literal_ replacement and is case-_sensitive_, _invariably_ in Windows PowerShell, _by default_ in PowerShell (Core) 7+.

Answer (score 3):

Your code is currently failing to replace that string because [`-replace`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_comparison_operators?view=powershell-7.3#replacement-operator) uses [Regular Expressions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_regular_expressions?view=powershell-7.4) to find the specified pattern.

You can either use [`.Replace`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.replace?view=net-8.0) instead of `-replace` (case sensitive method) for literal replacement:

```bash
(Get-Content lit.bib -Raw).Replace('{\textunderscore }', '_') |
    Out-File -encoding UTF8 lit_t.bib
```

Or use `-replace` (case insensitive method) but [escape the regex special characters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.escape?view=net-8.0) (for a literal match):

```bash
(Get-Content lit.bib -Raw) -replace [regex]::Escape('{\textunderscore }'), '_' |
    Out-File -encoding UTF8 lit_t.bib
```

Answer (score -1):

To replace the expression "{\textunderscore }" with "_" in a text file using PowerShell, you can use the following command:

```
(Get-Content lit.bib) -replace '{\textunderscore }', '_' | Set-Content -Encoding utf8 lit_t.bib
```

Comment: It's easy to verify that your solution won't work, using the following: `'[{\textunderscore }]' -replace '{\textunderscore }', '_'`. With _string_ input, your - ineffective - `Set-Content`-based solution is in effect the same as the - equally ineffective - `Out-File`-based solution in the question.